# If you change the timeInMillis value of Calendar.getInstance() to int, can it be a unique id?

Tags: android, uuid, android-calendar, unique-id

During Android app development, each item tries to attach a unique int type id. I thought that the point at which the item was created is unique, so after calling Calendar.getInstance(), I thought to give it by changing the value of timeInMillis to toInt(). Even if it is transformed into an int like this, does the value become unique?

### Ex)

```
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
 val longId = calendar.timeInMillis          // 1611807420557
 val intId = calendar.timeinMillis.toInt()   // 1194684557
```

As a result of my testing, the above values ​​were output. Is the 1194684557 value changed to int a unique id?

Comment: The `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Consider using `ZonedDateTime` and/or `Instant` and/ or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) if for Android API level under 26.

Comment: The time in millis that you get from the old-fashioned `Calendar` class can be had from modern sources too. I am using `Instant`. `(int) Instant.parse("2021-01-05T12:00:00Z").toEpochMilli()` yields -764 736 000. `(int) Instant.parse("2021-02-24T05:02:47.296Z").toEpochMilli()` too yields -764 736 000. So no, your idea does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toInt()` isn't a good idea because it won't work if your long is out of range of the int. I would recommend to divide the millis by something like 1000. And then convert it to int.
Try something like that:

```kotlin
val intId = (longId / 1000).toInt()
```

Comment: It will still overflow in `int` in 18 years from now. [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).